# Getting error when i download cpanel on centOS vps server?

Tags: cpanel, web-deployment, web-hosting, vps

**I want to download cPanel on my centOS 7 vps server. when i run this script**

```
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

**I am getting this type of error:-**

```
2022-06-23 10:31:17  367 [3558] (ERROR): The installation process found evidence that the following control panels were installed on this server:
2022-06-23 10:31:17  368 [3558] (ERROR): cPanel & WHM
2022-06-23 10:31:17   44 [3558] ( INFO): cPanel is here to help! Our Technical Support team is just a click away at https://support.cpanel.net/ or you can conta                                         ct Customer Service via email cs@cpanel.net
2022-06-23 10:31:17  369 [3558] (FATAL): You must install cPanel & WHM on a clean server.
```

**I also Reinstall my operating system and nothing in the server**

Please any one know about that then help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Because cPanel is already installed on this server anyhow. Reinstall the CentOS in the VPS then try again with the command. Your command seems okay.

Comment: i also try this many times but error still coming...